# How do I get the files from a public github repo pull request on my local computer?

Tags: github

How do I get the files from a public repo pull request on my local computer?

A developer submitted a pull request to a public repo (to which I don't have write access).

I want to test his code before I acknowledge the pull request.

How do I get the master of the public repo + his pull request on my local in order to compile and test it?

Comment: I am hoping there is a better way than going to the raw file in the web browser and doing a right-click save as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click the 'info' icon to get the git commands you need to run.

[image]

You can also get any pull request as a patch by appending .patch to the url.  For instance:

https://github.com/github/github-services/pull/146.patch

Comment: I want to do the same but don't see that Green label anywhere on the Pull Request. Is that only available if you own/contribute to the repo in question? Because I don't - I just want to locally pull someone elses pull request which hasn't been pulled by the owner.